# Structuring program navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm developing a WPF application and I use Caliburn-Micro for handling the MVVM plumbing.  I use the Event Aggregator in CM to listen for navigation events.  Currently there isn't any commonality between the events.  So I have a OrderNavigationEvent, QuoteNavigationEvent, PriceBookNavigationEvent, etc...

I thought about making a general NavigationEvent class along a few enums that has all of the different types I would navigation events I would need.  Something like:

```
public enum NavigationDestinations
{
    Orders,
    Quotes,
    PriceBook
}

public enum NavigationOptions
{   
    Open,
    New,
    Listing
}

public class NavigationEvent
{
    public NavigationDestinations NavigationDestination {get; set;}
    public NaviationOptions NavigationOption {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

And then I can setup a Handle(NavigationEvent message) which then boils down to a huge collection of IF statements. It would work, but **ugh**.

Any suggestions on how I can approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suggest creating a "base" class of an event class that has **NO** commonality in it. You're breaking the **Single Responsibility Principle**. Your three events needs to do something different whenever it is published.

I suggest to break them apart and call the _eventAggregator.Publish(**class**) to a class and let the subscriber subscribe from it.

If ever you would need THREE of those events in one class then do three **`IHandle<OrderNavigationEvent>, IHandle<QuoteNavigationEvent>, IHandle<PriceBookNavigationEvent>`**

And let the class subscribe **`_eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);`** to it and then you would eliminate your multi IF's check for it and you get to concentrate on a certain piece of functionality when a certain event is published.

Then you would have three different handles for each of this events

```
public void Handle(QuoteNavigationEvent eventArgs)
{
  ...
}

public void Handle(OrderNavigationEvent eventArgs)
{
 ...
}

public void Handle(PriceBookNavigationEvent eventArgs)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: The setup you describe is exactly what I have now.  The main thing I don't like about it (other than a metric ton of IHandles) is that I want to implement forward/backward navigation like a browser.  I'm not sure how I would take my current setup above and avoid having something worthy of a mention on the Daily WTF.

Comment: Actually it was quite easy to due the backwards/forwards.  I thought that an Interface was part of the inheritance tree and that I would have to cast objects back from INavigationHistory to their original event.  But I didn't have to do that!

Comment: Wait, if you wanted to implement a forward/bcakward navigation like browser why not use the Page Control? It gives you that..